# Как вы используете в своём проекте связку Rx и ButterKnife?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rxjava

Пилю собственное приложение и хотелось бы узнать мнение опытных программистов по поводу связок библиотек для написания структурированного, красивого кода.
На данный момент в проекте есть GSON, ButterKnife, EventBus, RxBinding, RxKotlin.
В частности, пример - есть кнопка на экране, которую хочется забиндить на клик.
Можно сделать это с помощью ButterKnife

```
@OnClick(R.id.add_content)
fun addItem() {
//TODO
}
```

Можно это сделать с помощью Rx:

```
btnAdd!!.clicks(//TODO)
```

1. Какие общие советы будут по использованию этих библиотек вместе?
2. EventBus использую для того что бы по нажатию в одной активити создавался элемент в RecyclerView в другой активити. Но чувствую что как-то коряво - можно ведь сделать это с помощью Rx?

Comment: ButterKnife же уже устарел c появлением ViewBinding

Comment: Вот я и хочу узнать как сейчас делать наиболее правильно

Comment: kotlin synthetic самый удобный. butterKnife это ваще дно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете Kotlin то вам не нужен ButterKnife в принципе. Вы можете обращаться к вашим `View` из `XML` прям по id. В `Activity` после вызова метода `setContentView()`, во `Fragment-е` после вызова `onViewCreated()`.

Например:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    welcomeMessage.text = "Hello Kotlin!"
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       
        welcomeMessage.text = "Hello Kotlin!"
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView.ViewHolder:**

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(data: Data) {
            itemView.welcomeMessage.text = "Hello Kotlin!"
            }
        }
    }
```

[Здесь](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/kotlin-android-extensions-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-42ad43b029d7) статья на эту тему.

Comment: Спасибо. И клик я так понимаю через Rx делать?

Comment: Ну если вы используете RX Binding то делайте через RX, если нет то button.setOnClickListener{} вам в помощь. С этим всем можно делать тоже самое что и с View найденной в Java с помощью  findViewById

Comment: А в адаптерах RecyclerView можно аналогично делать?

Comment: и небольшое уточнение,я правильно понимаю что обращаться напрямую по id можно только в рамках onViewCreated и onCreate?

Comment: Да, только там 1 нюанс. Все обращения идут через itemView ViewHolder-a. Например itemView.textView.text = "hello word"

Comment: В любом месте после вызова этих методов. Т.е. до того как вызовется setContentView в Activity у вас нет макета, а значит обращаться не к чему. Во фрагменте после того как прошел колбек onViewCreated, раньше у вас еще нет раздутого макета. Можно и в onCreateView но только через view которую вы возвращаете в методе. Типа как в ViewHolder. Но обычно сетится все просто в onViewCreated или позже

Comment: Дополнил ответ с ViewHoldee